# Upgrade older msi from Wix custom BA Bundle

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

We are upgrading our WIX msi installer (not a bundle) with manual pre-requisites to a Managed custom Bootstrapped application Bundle. The boot strapped custom installer bundle exe works fine for fresh installs. But if we want to upgrade our older product which is just an msi, we are in trouble. This is what I am trying to do

1. Detect RelatedMsiFeatureHandler detects there is an older msi package installed.
2. I am handling the Plan events for individual packages and setting the states as desired. For ex: state = Present for install
3. I cannot to Apply(UpdateReplace) because I do not have an older Bundle,

The million dollar question is how do I upgrade this msi package? 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was set the MsiProperty UPGRADE=1 in Bundle.wxs for the relevant Msi Package in the chain. This made sure that when the Bundle.exe is run the specific msi is upgraded BTW: this is the first version of Bundle for us. We had just an MSI before for installation.

```html
<MsiPackage DisplayName="Installing Main Product" SourceFile="$(var.Path_Setup)" DisplayInternalUI="no" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" >
        ***<MsiProperty Name="UPGRADE" Value="1"/>***
        <MsiProperty Name="NAS_PATH" Value="[NasBackupPath]"/>
        <MsiProperty Name="NAS_BAK_TIME" Value="[BackupTime]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
  </Chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone having similar issue (WIX 3.10)

this statment under the installer's Product will resolve the issue. You must update the version of the product and product upgrade code must be same with previous install.

"AllowSameVersionUpgrades" = yes will make sure not to install same product side by side.